# How to chain ranges::view conditionally?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

Simply put, how do I programnatically branch on a `view` chain construct?

Because now what I can think of is just `#if`, in which is not a very good idea.

```
auto adaptor =
   view::drop(x0)
#if branch1
   | view::drop(x1)
#elif branch2
   | view::filter(ft1)
#endif
   | view::stride(s1);
```

---

### Updated

After googling awhile, I just think the only available option now is that you have to "*blend*" logic into `view::xxx_while` or any predicatable view with mutable lambda or whatever.

However, it turns out quite okey already.

```
auto adaptor =
   view::drop(x0)
   | view::drop_while([captures](auto&&) mutable { ...blend it here... })
   | view::filter([captures](auto&&) mutable { ..blend it here... })
   | view::stride(s1);
```

Anyway, if `view::enable_if` can some how be avaiable in the future, I think the code will look way more straight forward than this.

Comment: I have troubles understanding what do you mean exactly. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Fureeish kinda too ugly to put at the first place. sorry.

Comment: Given the fact thaty views are lazy, their declarations should not introduce any performance hits. In this case, what's wrong with using plain `if`s? Just `auto rng = prev | ...` and so on. Ranges are not quite suited for such branches. They are lightweight and it's fine to create many of them. The unused ones should not typically occupy much (or sometimes any) space.

Comment: @Fureeish Wish there should be `view::enable_if` :-)

Comment: Are these conditions constant expressions?

Comment: This is not a good place for such discussion, but I really wonder - why? Ranges represent chains of operations and while I agree that the logic behind conditionally performing an operation is solid, I don't believe it's really necessary in the ranges world. I can see it begin problematic due to them having different types but I don't think the `if` solution is bad either.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah I forgot about that. This renders `#if` useless.

Comment: @Fureeish Between branched selecting plenty of chains versus one chain with `view::enable_if`, I think one chain code will look way way more straight forward. Don't you think?

Comment: I completely agree after some thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not doing that. Instead of this hypotetical code:

```
auto adaptor =
   view::drop(x0)
#if branch1
   | ranges::drop(x1)
#elif branch2
   | ranges::filter(ft1)
#endif
   | ranges::stride(s1);
```

You should incorporate that logic into the filter:

```
auto adaptor =
   view::drop(x0)
   | ranges::filter([](auto&& x){ return branch2 && ft1(x); })
   | ranges::stride(s1);
```

---

If you really want to compose a range adapter with some compile time value, you can use if statements like that:

```
auto get_adapter() {
    if constexpr(branch1)
        return view::drop(x0) | ranges::drop(x1) | ranges::stride(s1);
    else if constexpr (branch2)
        return view::drop(x0) | ranges::filter(ft1) | ranges::stride(s1);
    else
        return view::drop(x0) | ranges::stride(s1);
}
```

Comment: I fix my question. I just want to drop some on a condition and also filter on another condition.

Comment: Should it not be `return branch2 && ft1(x);`? You are assuming that `ft1` has no side effect